# How to set elevation of parent view taking into consideration all its children?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-elevation

I have `RelativeLayout` parent, which has 2 children horizontally positioned next to each other. First children is `LinearLayout` has custom background shape and some content in it and second one is `ImageView` which is representing custom shaped end of background. As they are next to each other, they are forming one single uninterrupted background.

Problem is that if I set `android:elevation="8dp"` to `RelativeLayout` parent, Its not visible at all. I tried `clipToPadding` false, but nothing has changed.

LinearLayout has dynamic height (`wrap_content`) and `ImageView` is stretching based on first layout height(`android:layout_alignTop, android:layout_alignBottom`)

Here is quick sketch of that layout (I cant share actual screenshot - im under NDA).

[image]

Mockup layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable name="CustomRes" type="com.project.utils.CustomResources"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:elevation="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_small">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/endElement"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round_left"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/blue">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/infoParent"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/infoMain"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/baseInfoLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/infoTime"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/city"
                            style="@style/item_text_secondary"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="--"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/station"
                            style="@style/item_text_primary"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="--" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/duration"
                            style="@style/item_text_primary"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="--" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/infoTime"
                        style="@style/item_activated_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:text="--" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/itemTimeLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
                        android:layout_below="@id/baseInfoLayout"
                        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
                            style="@style/item_activated_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:text="Activated at: " />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/activatedAt"
                            style="@style/item_activated_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/timeLabel"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:text="--"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/endElement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/mainContentLayout"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/mainContentLayout"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
            android:background="@drawable/item_ending_element" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Does the RelativeLayout have a background? If not, try applying one to see if the shadow appears.

Comment: Nope, but Ive added background just to test, nothing appeared.

Comment: OK. I understand that you are under an NDA, but can you mock up a short layout that exhibits the same problem? That would help.

Comment: Added some mockup

Comment: The XML helped. With a transparent background on the _RelativeLayout_, there is no shadow. If I set the background to "@android:color/white" the shadow appears. If I remove everything in the _RelativeLayout_ and set the width/height to `match_parent`/`150dp`, the result is the same. If you don't get the same result, it could be an issue with the API level or related.

Comment: White background is then overlaping with transparent part in ImageView. Parent cant have any colored background. I cant draw any color under those "spikes/tears" in ImageView.

Comment: So, if the _RelativeLayout_ has a non-transparent background, you do see a shadow but the layout can't have a background because it interferes with the look of the other views. You need the transparent background _RelativeLayout_ to case a shadow. Is that correct?

Comment: Thats correct. If I set color to white, shadow is drawn around edges of ImageView (rectangular shadow). But it is not taking into consideration transparent content inside ImageView. Because ImageView src image has parts of it transparent. 

What I got from it is that Android is not smart enough to work with transparency inside ImageView content.

Comment: I think that you are right; it's one of those Android things. You might consider creating a view whose sole purpose is to be the shadow. Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70227950/6287910) might be helpful or, at least, offer some insight.