# What can be the reason of this weird halogen symbol in FAB in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, floating-action-button

I am trying to use some animations on my FAB. I have different themes and in one of them when I open the FAB (after it undergoes) the animation I see this halogen symbol. Tried debugging for couple of hours now, but can't find the possible reason.

I am not sure if it is due to the animation I am trying to use, but I have not added anything which can make this happen. I am very much confused and any help would be appreciated. Even if you have any idea what could be the possibilities of fixing this please mention them in comment so I can try.

This is how it looks :

[image]

Comment: That's Android's material shadow artifact, which you're seeing because the FAB has a translucent background. The easiest way to get rid of it is to use only opaque backgrounds, or to disable the shadow altogether.

Comment: Ah!! I get it, you said the easiest way is to use only opaque backgrounds. May I know what are the other possible approaches to fix it

Comment: The only other straightforward method I know is disabling the shadow (which I was editing my comment above to add). If you really actually need see-through backgrounds with shadows, just without the artifact, it'll take some sort of workaround, AFAIK.

Comment: I would need to find that workaround, as I think it would be something which could help me here. Any links, blogs where I can read about it? Any approaches?

Comment: Oops, wrong tab. Here are those links again, since I just deleted my last comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70227950, https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. I realized that using a library for the project won't be an idle solution because I just need it inside FAB. I just choose my FAB to have opaque background and it's working well.